# unicode-math + siunitx + lualatex = long compile times. Why?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math, performance

The following MWE, compiled under several situations (with appropriate lines removed) gives the following timings (with all output files removed between runs), as timed by `Measure-Command` on Windows 7 Powershell with TL2014:

```
Engine   | unicode-math?   | sisetup options             | Time
-------------------------------------------------------------------
lualatex | unicode-math    | per-mode=symbol-or-fraction | ~53 sec
lualatex | unicode-math    | per-mode=default            | ~5 sec
lualatex | no unicode-math | per-mode=symbol-or-fraction | ~2 sec
lualatex | fontspec        | per-mode=symbol-or-fraction | ~4 sec
xelatex  | unicode-math    | per-mode=symbol-or-fraction | ~4 sec
xelatex  | no unicode-math | per-mode=symbol-or-fraction | ~2 sec
pdflatex | no unicode-math | per-mode=default            | ~1 sec
pdflatex | no unicode-math | per-mode=symbol-or-fraction | ~1 sec
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why does adding the `per-mode=symbol-or-fraction` with `unicode-math` increase the compile time by an order of magnitude in `lualatex`?

Binary versions:

```
LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (rev 4971)
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    per-mode = symbol-or-fraction,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\text{at $p=\SI{1.0}{\MPa}$:}\begin{cases}
v(T) &= v_1 + \left(T - T_1\right)\frac{v_2 - v_1}{T_2 - T_1} \\
v(\SI{220}{\degreeCelsius}) &= \SI{0.2060}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram} + \left(\SI{220}{\degreeCelsius} - \SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}\right) \frac{\SI{0.2275}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram} - \SI{0.2060}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram}}{\SI{240}{\degreeCelsius} - \SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}} \\
v(\SI{220}{\degreeCelsius}) &= \SI{0.21675}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram}
\end{cases}\\
\text{at $p=\SI{1.5}{\MPa}$:}\begin{cases}
v(T) &= v_1 + \left(T - T_1\right)\frac{v_2 - v_1}{T_2 - T_1} \\
v(\SI{220}{\degreeCelsius}) &= \SI{0.1325}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram} + \left(\SI{220}{\degreeCelsius} - \SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}\right) \frac{\SI{0.1483}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram} - \SI{0.1325}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram}}{\SI{240}{\degreeCelsius} - \SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}} \\
v(\SI{220}{\degreeCelsius}) &= \SI{0.1404}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram}
\end{cases}\\
\text{at $T=\SI{220}{\degreeCelsius}$:}\begin{cases}
v(p) &= v_1 + \left(p - p_1\right)\frac{v_2 - v_1}{p_2 - p_1} \\
v(\SI{1.4}{\MPa}) &= \SI{0.21675}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram} + \left(\SI{1.4}{\MPa} - \SI{1.0}{\MPa}\right) \frac{\SI{0.1404}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram} - \SI{0.21675}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram}}{\SI{1.5}{\MPa} - \SI{1.0}{\MPa}} \\
v(\SI{1.4}{\MPa}) &= \SI{0.1557}{\meter\cubed\per\kilogram}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have LuaTeX 0.79.1 as well, running on an early-2014 MacBookPro model with a 2.8 GHz Corei7 CPU and with OSX 10.10.2. With the `unicode-math` package loaded, I get a compile time of between 5 and 6 seconds with the `per-mode=symbol-or-fraction` set. Without that option, it takes between 1 and 2 seconds to compile.

Comment: @Mico I have an unknown year Dell Optiplex 9010 with a Core i7 at 3.4 GHz and 8 GB RAM. I guess you don't see the order of magnitude, but its still a factor of 5. Seems strange!

Comment: I can confirm that the difference in speed with/without `per-mode=symbol-or-fraction` is *dramatic*.

Comment: There are some performance issues which are really beyond my control (I have looked for anything obvious at my end). Here, the thing to remember is that doing this sort of 'auto-detection' uses `\mathchoice`, so typesets everything four times (display, text, script, scriptscript).

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for looking! Based on some reading I've done (that I'm not sure is relevant), it may be due to font loading in lualatex: http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2013-March/004114.html If lualatex loads fonts for each of the required sizes, that might take a long time...

Comment: @darthbith Here, with the same hardware as yours (Dell Optiplex 9010 with a Core i7 at 3.4 GHz), with `per-mode=symbol-or-fraction`, and with TeXLive 2014, I get a compile time of ~5sec. My OS is Linux...

Comment: @PaulGaborit On a Linux machine with a Xeon X5650 at 2.67 GHz with TL2014, I get ~9 sec with LuaLaTeX as compared to ~5 sec with XeLaTeX or ~4 sec without setting `per-mode` with LuaLaTeX. So maybe it's (mostly?) a Windows thing?

Comment: How is this "too broad"?  Voting to reopen!